# Building pgadmin3-1.20.0 in CentOS 7 with PostgreSQL-9.4

Tags: postgresql, build, centos, configure, pgadmin

I want to build pgadmin3-1.20.0 in CentOS 7, so I enter:

```
./configure
```

But I got this error:

```
configure: error: Could not find your PostgreSQL installation. You might need to use the --with-pgsql=DIR configure option
```

And when I use following command:

```
./configure --with-pgsql=/usr/pgsql-9.4/
```

this error will be raised:

```
configure: error: you must specify a valid PostgreSQL 8.4+ installation with --with-pgsql=DIR
```

Pgsql is up and has not any problem. How can I fix this error.

Comment: Did you try `--with-pgsql=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin`?

Comment: Yes and now error is : configure: error: Could not find your PostgreSQL installation in /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/

Comment: Does the `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin` directory exist? Is it empty? How did you install Postgresql?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, Yes , /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin exist and is not empty. As I mentioned psql can be run.  To insatll PostgreSQL, I used guidelines in this link :http://www.unixmen.com/postgresql-9-4-released-install-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to install the libraries that are specified in this other post?

https://serverfault.com/questions/453430/install-pgadmin-in-debian-server