# Install pgAdmin 3 without postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I try to install pgAdmin3 for postgresql 9.4 but have an error:

> Could not find your PostgreSQL installation. You might need to use the
>   --with-pgsql=DIR configure option.

I saw some questions in this resource, for example 
[Building pgadmin3-1.20.0 in CentOS 7 with PostgreSQL-9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728994/building-pgadmin3-1-20-0-in-centos-7-with-postgresql-9-4)

But I've postgresql running in Docker and have not locally installation.
Any ideas how to compile pgAdmin without postgresql installation?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is supported. You'd likely have to figure out which libraries and other files are essential to the build, and fool the process into thinking you have a Postgres installation. It seems like a lot more effort then just installing Postgres would be.

Comment: And how exactly did you try to install pgAdmin? Can't you just install the pre-built binaries from a repository: http://pgadmin.org/download/